# How to upload an image with flask-admin and flask-sqlachelmy?

Tags: python, flask, file-upload

I am creating a simple blog and I use flask-admin to generate articles. Each article is based on the model Admin given below. I don't know how to define the variable cover so that I find an input to upload an image in my admin panel.

```py
# importing some modules ...
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
admin = Admin(app, template_mode='bootstrap3')

class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(255))
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    cover = # which type here ?
    author = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now())
    edited_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now())

class AdminArticleView(ModelView):

    # some specific code here

    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        if isinstance(model, Article):
            # some code ...
            # may be work here to enable uploading an image in flask-admin ?

admin = Admin(app, template_mode='bootstrap3')
admin.add_view(AdminArticleView(Article, db.session))
```

I assume that I will have to change the view AdminArticleView, but I am really new in flask... My idea is to register the path of the image in cover, so I would define it using db.Column(db.String, nullable=True). Then, I would upload the file and store its path in cover (I don't know how to do so too..). But, I see a problem with this idea : defining the attribute cover as db.String would lead to add a text input in the front-end and it would thus not be possible to upload an image there. We need a file input there. I think there is another way more flask-pythonic to solve this problem. Does anyone have an idea to help me ? Any answers will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. Somewhat...

It will be a db.String column and it will store the path of the image file.
When you want to display the image on your page, it will be using `url_for()` or `url()` and using the `<img>` tag.

It will look something like this ::

In the route :

```
image_file = url_for('static', filename='coverpics/'+current_user.cover)
return render_template(#your other args..., cover_url=image_file)
```

Here, `current_user` is to automatically fetch the current logged in user and then make any DB queries you want related to that user.

In the template :
`<img href="{{cover_url}}">`

But since you are an absolute beginner, I assume that you don't even know how to save the uploaded cover pic. So there's a good amount of work that you will have to do for implementing this functionality in your application.

I'd recommend that you watch this tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=803Ei2Sq-Zs

It's on how to implement profile pics in your flask webapp, but I'm sure you can learn from it and implement cover pics. In fact, watch the whole series. You won't regret it.

Feel free to ask more!

Comment: Thank you @wiserdivisor I will watch it now and try to do something on my side. Once my code works, I will refresh this post. Hope to see your comments soon :)

Comment: If you found this answer satisfactory, then please do mark it as Best Answer!

Comment: I will by tomorrow. I've almost solved my issue and I will share the solution here :D